# "Expected whitespace character" when running a custom inputKey

Tags: scala, sbt

I am creating a custom `inputKey` which looks like

```
val rating = inputKey[Option[Int]]("How will you rate this course?")
rating := {
  import complete.DefaultParsers._
  import complete.Parser
  val r: Parser[Int] = IntBasic.examples("<rating>")
  r.result
}
```

This sits in file `projectRoot/build.sbt`.

I try to run this on `sbt shell` using multiple times, each time it fails

```
sbt:Hello> rating 1
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Expected '/'
[error] rating 1
[error]        ^
sbt:Hello>
```

Then,

```
sbt:Hello> show "rating 3"
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Expected 'Global'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected 'Zero'
[error] Expected 'ThisBuild'
[error] Expected 'ProjectRef('
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected configuration ident
[error] Expected key
[error] show "rating 3"
[error]      ^
sbt:Hello>
```

Also, as

```
sbt:Hello> rating "5"
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Expected '/'
[error] rating "5"
[error]        ^
sbt:Hello>
```

I do not know what I am missing here. Can someone please point out my mistake here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is a space character before the integer, try using `Space ~> IntBasic` parser combination like so

```
lazy val rating = inputKey[Int]("How will you rate this course?")
rating := {
  import complete.DefaultParsers._
  val rating = (Space ~> IntBasic).examples("<rating>").parsed
  println(s"Rating input = $rating")
  rating
}
```

Executing `rating 3` in sbt should now output `Rating input = 3`

Comment: aha! This is what I didn't know. I am not sure how to read `(Space ~> IntBasic)`